# How to replace Vendor with Add to Cart button on Slick Slider - Shopify Debut theme?

Tags: shopify, liquid, slick.js, shopify-template

How can I remove the Vendor name and replace with an Add to Cart button on this Slick carousel? This is for the Shopify Debut Theme. Thanks for your help :)

[image: I would like to replace Vendor with an Add to Cart button]

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps for Debut theme for Add to cart button on product grid.

1. In Shopify Admin select "Online Store" and click on Themes.
2. Choose your main theme.
3. Click the . . . on the top left-right (see below) and hit "Edit code" option.
4. Open Snippets -> "product-card-grid.liquid" File and paste below code at the end of the page code.

---

Here is that code:

```
<form method="post" action="/cart/add">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ product.variants.first.id }}" />
  <input min="1" type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="1"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" class="btn" />
</form>
```

Comment: This worked for collections pages, but not on the Slick carousel on homepage. Thank you for the reply

Comment: Can you please share a link of your store? So, I will check and give you a solution of slick.

Comment: Thank you for share your store link here, I've checked that and you have get product details using custom code not from the "product-card-grid.liquid" file. So, you need to add above my given code there when you have get product details using custom code as per you have added in "product-card-grid.liquid" file code.

Comment: I do not understand

Comment: are you able to give me access of your Shopify Store? I'll help you to add button there.

Comment: Yes, I can send an invite to give you access to account.. what is your email address to send invite to?

Comment: I'll check that after sometime. Once I'll complete that then inform you about that.

Comment: Thank you. It is much appreciated

Comment: I've added the "Add to Cart" button in your product slider. So, please check and confirm that. Sorry for the late.

Comment: Excellent Thank you! I have sent you an email inquiry with one further question

Comment: I've given a reply to you about that in email.

Comment: Is there any way to make this form NOT redirect to the cart? I want several products in a popup where I would like the customer to be able to add multiple products to the cart from the same popup. This popup appears when someone presses "Add to cart" on a PDP.

Comment: Yes, @R. Srour, it is possible to add a product to the cart without redirect to the cart page. can I help you about that?

Comment: Yes I'd love it if you could help me with that!